# Declarar e referenciar uma variável no SQL Editor Context do Firebird

Tags: firebird, declaração-de-variável

é possível declarar e referenciar uma variável no contexto do SQL Editor?

Sei como fazer em MySQL. Para exemplificar melhor, segue um exemplo em MySQL do que eu quero.

```
SET @var = 10;
SELECT @var;
```

Desde já agradeço!